# Creating an equation from this triangle.

Tags: geometry

Pretty much stuck at where I should go. Any guidance?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbllI.jpg]

Comment: Do you know the [angle bisector theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing the angle bisector theorem and denoting $BC = x$ you just need to note that $$\frac{6}{x}=\frac{4}{15-x}.$$ Solve for $x=BC$.

Comment: +1 I didn't know whether to assume the OP knew the theorem. Spot on!

Answer (score 4):

Use the law of sines in triangle ABD and also in triangle BDC; use what you know about $AB+BC$, what you know about angles ABD and DBC, and what you know about angles ADB and BDC.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Use the *[**law of sines**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)* for each of triangles $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle BDC$.
- You know that $AB + BC + CA = 25$ ( = perimeter), and
- $AC = 4 + 6 = 10$, so $AB + BC = 25 - 10 = 15$
- You know that $\angle ABD \cong \angle CBD$, and the $\angle ADB + \angle BDC = 180^\circ$ (as they are are supplementary).

You have all the information you need to solve for $BC$

Comment: Nice to see you too, @Babak. I'm assuming our time zones differ significantly! ~08:00 my time, now!